# In a table of timed observations from multiple sensors, how to optimally retrieve the last observation for each sensor

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

My table looks as follows:

| sensor | time | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 2021-01-05 04:10:14 | 3.14159 |
| AAA | 2021-01-05 05:08:07 | 3.94756 |
| ABC | 2021-01-05 03:40:54 | 4.32543 |

I'm looking for a query that retrieves the rows corresponding to the last observation for each sensor, i.e.:

| sensor | time | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 2021-01-05 05:08:07 | 3.94756 |
| ABC | 2021-01-05 03:40:54 | 4.32543 |

After doing some research I came across this solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (sensor) sensor, time, value
FROM observations
ORDER BY sensor, time DESC
```

The problem with the above is that it's rather costly for large tables.

A possible solution would be to have another table holding only the last observation for each sensor, separate from the one holding all the historical ones. While that would work, I was wondering if there is something more elegant, i.e. that allows me to keep a single table, while having a better performance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `distinct on()` is typically the most efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function such as `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
SELECT sensor, time, value
 FROM
 (
  SELECT o.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sensor ORDER BY time DESC) AS rn
    FROM observations o ) oo
 WHERE rn = 1
```

assuming ties occur for time values, then `DENSE_RANK()` function might be used instead in order to include all equal time values within the result set.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=de9f36e0a67e382d4a04490ce1473e43)</kbd>

Comment: `distinct on ()` is typically more efficient than a window function

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the recursive CTE:

```
with recursive t as (
    (select sensor, time, value
     from observations
     order by sensor, time desc limit 1)
    union all
    (select o.sensor, o.time, o.value
     from observations as o join t on (o.sensor > t.sensor)
     order by o.sensor, o.time desc limit 1))
select * from t;
```

Index on `observations(sensor, time desc)` could help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (sensor) sensor, time, value
FROM observations
ORDER BY sensor, time DESC
```

You want an index on `(sensor, time desc)`.

With such an index, this is probably the fastest method for doing what you want.